# Does POSIX guarantee certain usernames?

Tags: users, posix

In the POSIX Definitions there is specific [section 3.424](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_424), User Database, which defines what information should be related to each user ID. However through out the document, I couldn't find (at least not via simple <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> search) mention of either `root` nor any of the typical system usernames, such as `syslog`, `bin`, `daemon`, `nobody`, `sys`. There doesn't seem to be mention of these in [newgrp utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/newgrp.html) definitions either, to which the 3.424 refers.

This begs the question: does POSIX require existence of certain system-level usernames or UIDs ? Is `root` user even required to be `root`, or is it theoretically possible to have POSIX-compliant system where the most powerful system account is not called `root` or has non-zero UID?

Comment: POSIX explicitly does not standardize system utilities and administration part.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Any source for that statement ? I am curious to which extent then POSIX  does limit administration part. But utilities and interfaces are in fact standardized, at least basic utilities such as `cat`, `/bin/sh`, etc

Comment: Now I do not find it explicitly (but the first paragraph of the standard tell us that it is mostly about shell utilities and API for programmers and users (but not for administration). In fact you do not find very common "su, passwd, mount" as utilities. "init" was cited only once (and just for zombies handling, not the system initialization)

Comment: Note: you linked the old POSIX. [It doesn't matter much on this question, but I want to put it into your attention]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a very good question. To which the simple answer would be no.

There is no guarantee, and you could even rename *root* to *toto*.

But your system would probably be unstable, since a lot of services and functions depend on certain usernames, typically, root.

Comment: That is a very tempting username, `toto` , I might consider using it in future :)  What about the UID itself ? Would these be "set in stone" so to speak ?

Comment: I agree, thinking to get toto's privileges. 
For the UID, 0 is the only one that is really always the *admin* user. The up to 99 are usually reserved.
Users used to start at 500, and now at 1000.
And the link here : http://www.linfo.org/uid.html